# adding a LDAP attribute with PHP

Tags: php, ldap

can't figure out what is the right syntax to add an additional attributes to a LDAP entry. When authenticating i get this array:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cn] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Vit Kos
                )

            [shortname] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vit.kos
                )

            [uid] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vit.kos
                )

            [mail] => Array
                (
                    [0] => vit.kos@email.com
                )

            [objectclass] => Array
                (
                    [0] => top
                    [1] => person
                    [2] => organizationalPerson
                    [3] => inetOrgPerson
                    [4] => dominoPerson
                )

            [givenname] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Vit
                )

            [userpassword] => Array
                (
                    [0] => password here
                )

            [sn] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Kos
                )

            [localadmin] => Array
                (
                    [0] => CN=#SysHQAdmin
                )

            [mailaddress] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Vit.Kos@email.com
                )

            [maildomain] => Array
                (
                    [0] => EMAIL
                )           


            [dn] => CN=Vit Kos,OU=###,O=EMAIL
        )

)
```

need to get an additional attribute member to be like

```
Array (
        [uid] => Array
            (
                [0] => vit.kos
            )

        [mail] => Array
            (
                [0] => vit.kos@email.com
            )
       [member] => Array
            (
                [0] => MEMBER HERE
            )
)
```

Never worked with LDAP before so it's quite confusing for me. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to retrieve an additional attribute that is already part of this user inside the LDAP server?

Comment: Indeed, are you trying to add this data from the directory (add modify operation), or retrieve some additional data from the directory that is already there but you are not able to retrieve?

Comment: No guys, there is no [member] attrib there, but i need to insert it and insert entries to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign data to the directory item that you retrieved above, you will perform a "modify" operation with [`ldap_modify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-modify.php). This is assuming that the schema of your database allows an attribute called `member` on this object - which it may not, you cannot simply add attributes to any object as and when you feel like it.

Firstly, you will need to create the entry or entries that will belong to the `member` attribute, and store them in an array:

```
$member = array (
  0 => "This is some data",
  1 => "This is some more data"
);
```

In order to tell the directory which object we want to modify, we will need it's DN. We can get this from the result of your previous search/list/read operation - the array that you show you have retrieved already (I assume this is stored in a variable called `$array`):

```
$dn = $array[0]['dn'];
```

Now we have all the information we need to perform the modify operation (I assume your connected/bound LDAP resource is held in a variable called `$ds`):

```
$result = ldap_modify($ds, $dn, array('member'=>$member));
```

After this, `$result` will be a boolean indicating whether the operation was successful or not. If it was unsuccessful, you can get an error message explaining why by calling:

```
$error = ldap_error($ds);
```

Comment: This seems working but i don't see any changes when performing the ldap_modify operation( How can I check my permissions maybe? thx for the help

Comment: If the operation fails, `ldap_modify` should be returning `false`. What type of LDAP server are you working with? AD, OpenLDAP or something else (and there isn't much else)?

Comment: i don't know that information. how can I get that info via php? using for LDAP JLDAP class used by Joomla! The ldap_modify returns 'OK' but i don't see any changes.

Comment: What type of device are you communicating with? Is it a Windows server, a telephone system or something else? LDAP is rarely used for anything other than those two situations...

Comment: It may be that the LDAP schema is not allowing you to add the attribute, but is not returning an error for whatever reason. You may need to contact the administrator of the directory server and ask them whether it is possible to do what you want.

Comment: it is a linux machine there, ldap is used for authenticating and storing users. Thank you for your help.. will check this with the ldap administrator